# Understanding this class intialization in python

Tags: python, python-class

I have this piece of code, part of a Spikingjelly neural network training functionality, which gets some errors on this line after running. I'm not quite experienced in Python, and I don't understand what class initialization type this is.

The class definition and the `__init__` looks like this:

```
class DVS128Gesture(sjds.NeuromorphicDatasetFolder):
    def __init__(
            self,
            root: str,
            train: bool = None,
            data_type: str = 'event',
            frames_number: int = None,
            split_by: str = None,
            duration: int = None,
            custom_integrate_function: Callable = None,
            custom_integrated_frames_dir_name: str = None,
            transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
            target_transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
    ) -> None:
```

And the intialization:

```
train_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset=DVS128Gesture(dataset_dir, train=True, use_frame=True, frames_num=T,
                            split_by=split_by, normalization=normalization),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=4,
    drop_last=True,
    pin_memory=True)
test_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset=DVS128Gesture(dataset_dir, train=False, use_frame=True, frames_num=T,
                            split_by=split_by, normalization=normalization),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
    num_workers=4,
    drop_last=False,
    pin_memory=True)
```

For example, class `DVS128Gesture` expects:

- A string (root) as the address of the dataset
- A bool (train) variable (which is not our interest right now)
- A string
- An integer value allocated to frames_number

**The problem:**
However, the initialization (at the bottom of the picture) is not according to that sequence; for example, `useframe=True` is used as the 3rd parameter while the class's 3rd parameter was `datatype: str = 'event'` .

**Questions:**

1. **Is the problem I mentioned above, really an error by the author?** or my misunderstanding of something?
2. **What's the meaning of a variable assignment during a class initialization?** For example, the 4th parameter of class initialization is written `framesnum=T`*.* Why not write 'T' directly? and why it was used `framesnum` instead of the original `frames_number` written in class definition?

I traced the mentioned variables the their declaration and classes they were used in and as much as I can understand, there is no other variables with the same name.

Comment: they are not positional arguments but keyword arguments (order not important), also the function must have a `**kwargs` argument to catch all the non specified keyword arguments

Comment: A **keyword argument** of a function call consists of the name of a function parameter, equal sign and value (an expression, to be precise). It can have a different order as in function definition because the parameter name tells where it belongs to. The `frames_num` versus `frames_number` seems an error to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. As others mentioned in the comments, this is a *keyword argument* (kwarg), for which order does not matter. You don't /have/ to use keywords when calling a function, but if you don't, then all of your arguments must be in the correct order and position.
2. This seems to be an error. You might use `frames_number=T` rather than just `T` so that it doesn't matter if you pass arguments in the correct order, but you're right that there's no `framesnum` kwarg in the original class declaration. There is also no `use_frame` or `normalization` kwarg, so I'm skeptical of what's going on here. It is possible to pass on keyword arguments for a parent class without specifically defining them in the child class's `__init__`, by adding `**kwargs` to the list of arguments and passing that to `super.init()`, but that isn't being done here, nor does the parent class actually have any of these keyword arguments in the first place.